# Sorting a List in C# using List.Sort(Comparison<T> comparison

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

I have created a class as follows:

```
public class StringMatch
{
   public int line_num;
   public int num_of_words;
}
```

I have created a list

```
List<StringMatch> sm;
```

it has few elements in it.

How do I sort this list using the `Comparison<T>` comparison overload?
The sorting must be done based on the `num_of_words` field.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use Linq [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for that -

```
sm = sm.OrderBy(i => i.num_of_words).ToList();
```

Comment: I wanted stable sorting and I found out that orderby does a stable sort. This was useful. Thanks!!

Comment: This makes a new list object.

Answer (score 45):

You can write lambda expression comparing two objects like this:

```
sm.Sort((x,y)=>x.num_of_words.CompareTo(y.num_of_words));
```

you can inverse sorting adding `-`

```
sm.Sort((x,y)=>-x.num_of_words.CompareTo(y.num_of_words));
```

Comment: You dont _need_ to use a lambda. Any delegate works just fine.

Comment: I am trying to learn more about using the List.Sort() method. In Microsoft's documentation, it indicates that this method has 3 argument-taking overloads... 
 (1) Sort(Comparison<T>)...   (2) Sort(Int32, Int32, IComparer<T>)...   (3) Sort(IComparer<T>). (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-6.0)

In your example above... is there any chance you could share which overload your lambda expression corresponds to? (Which overload you're using?)

Answer (score 2):

There is a usage example on the [official microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The example uses strings. Replace with `int` for your use.

```
private static int CompareDinosByLength(string x, string y)
{
   ...
}

List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();
dinosaurs.Add("Pachycephalosaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("");
dinosaurs.Add(null);
dinosaurs.Add("Mamenchisaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");
dinosaurs.Sort(CompareDinosByLength);
```

A little google goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Comparison` is an older and more clunky way of sorting collections. My advice would be to use the `OrderBy` method found in [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx):

```
var orderedSm = sm.OrderBy(x => x.num_of_words).ToList();
```

Comment: This creates a new `List` object and does not meet the question requirements that the `Sort` overload be used.

Answer (score 0):

For the mentioned list,

```
List<StringMatch> sm = new ();
```

You can sort ascending simply by,

```
sm.Sort((i, j) => i.num_of_words - j.num_of_words);
```

And descending by,

```
sm.Sort((i, j) => j.num_of_words - i.num_of_words);
```