# Is there anyway to sort a list based on difference of its two values?

Tags: c#, list, linq

So I have a list, `_students`, of object type `Student` and each `Student` object has a list, `Courses` , of object type `Course`. Each course object has two fields "Total no. of lectures" and "No. of lectures attended by the student". I want to sort this list with student objects by the difference of the two properties so guys who have taken all the courses would be at 0 index of the list.

I tried using something like this, but doesnt work.

```
_students.ForEach(c => c.Courses.OrderBy(le => le.Total - le.Attended))
```

Comment: Right now you order the courses instead of the students, You only do it for each student.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902248/sorting-a-list-in-c-sharp-using-list-sortcomparisont-comparison

Comment: My bad, Courses above is a list of object type Course

Comment: Please edit your question and add all missing details and code.

Comment: It will be helpful if you include example of what your parent and child lists look like?

Comment: Based on which course difference? Suppose stdA and stdB have taken two courses C1 and C2. stdA attended 8/10 and 8/10 of C1 and C2. Now stdB attended 7/10 and 9/10 of C1 and C2. The difference of which course will decide the ordering?

Comment: `but doesnt work.` How **specifically** does it not work?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do it this way :

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>(); 

students.Sort(delegate(Student s1, Student s2) { 
    int s1remainingLectures = 0;
    int s2remainingLectures = 0;
    foreach(Course c in s1.Courses) s1remainingLectures += c.total - c.Attended ;
    foreach(Course c in s2.Courses) s2remainingLectures += c.total - c.Attended ;
    return s1remainingLectures.CompareTo(s2remainingLectures); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `IComparable` on `Course`.

Here is a generic sample from another question:

```
public class BankAccount : IComparable<BankAccount>
{
    [...]

    public int CompareTo(BankAccount that)
    {
        return this.Balance.CompareTo(that.Balance);
    }
}
```

You can put your own logic inside the CompareTo function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your query you are looping inside the students list and order the courses they have.

If I understand you very well I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
 var orderedStudents=_students.ForEach(c => c.Courses.OrderBy(le => le.Total - le.Attended)).ToList();
```